# AWS MYSQL RDS connection over SSL

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

Using [Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.10/reference/configuration.html#line-number-f14834efb54224418f6f5aaf0687353e048bb8bc-3) and in `'driver' => 'pdo_mysql'`.

I am trying to connect with the AWS MYSQL instance over SSL, but getting failing.

As per MySQL and AWS [Document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-encrypted-connections.html#using-encrypted-connections-client-side-configuration) i have to provide `--ssl-mode=required`.

I have tried this: but it looks like [pdo_mysql](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.10/reference/configuration.html#pdo-mysql) doesn’t support `sslmode` option.

```
       $options = [
            'dbname' => $dbName,
            'user' => $user,
            'password' => $password,
            'host' => $host,
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
            'sslmode' => 'REQUIRED',
        ];
        return DriverManager::getConnection($options);
```

And even with PHP PDO also:

```
        $pemPath = __DIR__ . '/global-bundle.pem';
        $pdoOptions = [
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => file_get_contents($pemPath),
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
        ];
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;port=3306;dbname=$dbName", $user, $password, $pdoOptions);
        return DriverManager::getConnection(['pdo'=>$pdo]);
```

But getting no success.

The only way I got success when I connect using the command line:

```
mysql -uUser -p -h mysql-xx-abc.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com --ssl-mode=REQUIRED
```

my php version is 74

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually I found the solution.

[Doctrine DriverManager::getConnection](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.10/reference/configuration.html#line-number-f14834efb54224418f6f5aaf0687353e048bb8bc-10)

```
\Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams);
```

can accept `driverOptions` also so I am setting those options as per [PHP PDO Predefined Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php#pdo-mysql.constants) which are then forcing the connection to connect on SSL, same as in MySQL `--ssl-mode=REQUIRED`

```
        $pdoOptions = [
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '',
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
       ];

       $options = [
            'dbname' => $dbName,
            'user' => $user,
            'password' => $password,
            'host' => $host,
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
            'driverOptions' => $pdoOptions
        ];
        return DriverManager::getConnection($options);
```